# updating day in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Accidentally the server date was set to a wrong value for 1 day. You have correctly set the date now. But you want to change all the date entries made on that day. Write a query to change the day by 1 of all dates in the query table on 31st Jan 2013.

I have written the following query

UPDATE query SET date= DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE date="2013-01-31";

but it is not executing correctly

Comment: What's incorrect about it?

Comment: it's getting executed but the server shows wrong answer to this query

Comment: Can you paste that answer.

Comment: it worked using where day(date)=31 and month(date)=01 and year(date)=2013;   why is that

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. But you need to do following change.

```
UPDATE query SET date= DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE date(date)="2013-01-31";
```

I hope this works for you.